# How to add gradient in a specific area according to mouse movement?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm makng an app in HTML CSS JS, the usual. I want to know is there a way to apply gradient to only a specific location? Like, I have a complelety blank background, and I want to add a lighter gradient end to wherever the mouse moves. I have found a codepen which makes a custom cursor, and I have edited it -

```js
var body = document.getElementById("thediv")
var cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
var cursorinner = document.querySelector('.cursor2');
var a = document.querySelectorAll('a');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  cursor.style.transform = `translate3d(calc(${e.clientX}px - 50%), calc(${e.clientY}px - 50%), 0)`
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  cursorinner.style.left = x + 'px';
  cursorinner.style.top = y + 'px';
});

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  cursor.classList.add('click');
  cursorinner.classList.add('cursorinnerhover')
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  cursor.classList.remove('click')
  cursorinner.classList.remove('cursorinnerhover')
});

a.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    cursor.classList.add('hover');
  });
  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    cursor.classList.remove('hover');
  });
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
* {
  cursor: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#thediv {
  background-color: red
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #090909
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  font-family: montserrat;
  font-size: 40px;
}

a {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 0%;
  background: black;
  transition: width .3s ease;
}

a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  background: black;
}

.cursor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 15px), -50%);
}

.cursor2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: .3;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: width .3s, height .3s, opacity .3s;
}

.hover {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.cursorinnerhover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div id="thediv">
  <section>
    <a href="#">Hover Me</a>
  </section>
  <div class="cursor"></div>
  <div class="cursor2"></div>

</div>
```

So here it is a custom cursor, but I have tried to add changes to thediv and it isn't working, so can anyone please help me? It would help out a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```js
var body = document.getElementById("thediv")
var cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
var cursorinner = document.querySelector('.cursor2');
var a = document.querySelectorAll('a');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  cursor.style.transform = `translate3d(calc(${e.clientX}px - 50%), calc(${e.clientY}px - 50%), 0)`
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  cursorinner.style.left = x + 'px';
  cursorinner.style.top = y + 'px';
});

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  cursor.classList.add('click');
  cursorinner.classList.add('cursorinnerhover')
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  cursor.classList.remove('click')
  cursorinner.classList.remove('cursorinnerhover')
});

a.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    cursor.classList.add('hover');
  });
  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    cursor.classList.remove('hover');
  });
})

let myDiv = document.querySelector('.mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking');
myDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  let y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  myDiv.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
  myDiv.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
* {
  cursor: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#thediv {
  background-color: red
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #090909
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  font-family: montserrat;
  font-size: 40px;
}

a {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 0%;
  background: black;
  transition: width .3s ease;
}

a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0%;
  background: black;
}

.cursor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 15px), -50%);
}

.cursor2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: .3;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: width .3s, height .3s, opacity .3s;
}

.hover {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.cursorinnerhover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: .5;
}

.mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking {
  position: relative;
  background: #7983ff;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking section {
  position: relative;
}

.mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking:before {
  --size: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--x);
  top: var(--y);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, pink, transparent);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;
}

.mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking:hover:before {
  --size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="thediv" class="mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking">
  <section>
    <a href="#">Hover Me</a>
  </section>
  <div class="cursor"></div>
  <div class="cursor2"></div>

</div>
```